# Can I use MySQL date field type with custom date format

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with two fields: Date and Value.
My dates are quarters (Q1-2007, Q2-2008...).  I want to be able to use the following SQL query:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 ORDER BY Date`

How can I do this?

Comment: If it is possible to change the data model, it might be a good idea to change your single `Date` varchar column to the two integer columns: `Year` and `Quarter`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you want them ordered so that all the 2007 ones appear in order followed by the 2008 ones, etc. This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 ORDER BY SUBSTRING(Date, 4, 4), SUBSTRING(Date, 1, 2);
```

Assuming your date formats are all consistent and that your 'Date' column is actually a VARCHAR or similar...

Answer (score 1):

Use a date-column and decide on a date for each quarter. Then you can use the builtin functions for dates.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 ORDER BY Date` already sort the field `Date` as `Q1-2007`, `Q2-2007`, `Q3-2007`, `Q4-2007`? If you sort such strings, that should be how they are sorted.

If then I would create a database to contain those values, I would rather use 3 fields, and use two different fields for quarter, and year.